# How to get the text of a link which has children?

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to figure out how to get the text of a link which has children.
My html looks pretty much like this:

```
<a href="">
    The text I want to get
    <span> something I don't want to get </span>
</a>
```

I want to get only "The text I want to get" and not to include the children's text. 
Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#mylink").clone()
        .children()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .text()
```

Find example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F6LHU/):

Answer (score 3):

You can use `contents` to get all children, including text nodes.  Then filter to just get the text nodes.

```
var $textNodes = $("a").contents()
                    .filter(function(){
                        return this.nodeType == 3
                    })

var text = $textNodes.text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cnhxe/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the question provides enough information for all the possibilities of the children's tags and placement, but if the structure is always the same as the item supplied, you can do the following with jQuery:

```
var linkText = $("a").text();
linkText = linkText.replace($("a span").text(), "");
alert(linkText);
```

​

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In my case I don't know what the children's text is nor even the children's tagNames. They're generated dynamically. :)