# get parent li text by jquery

Tags: jquery

I need alert **thisparenttext** in following code by clicking on **clickedlicontent**

```
<script>
 $("#one").live("click",function(){
 var partxt=$(this).parent().parent().text();
 alert(partxt);
 });
</script>
<ul>
    <li>thisparenttext<ul><li id="one">clickedlicontent</li></ul></li>
    <li>bb</li>
</ul>
```

In other word, I want take only the text of first parent of clicked li, not all its all html codes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the text of a link which has children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450453/how-to-get-the-text-of-a-link-which-has-children) and [potentially others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+get+text+excluding+children&submit=search).

Comment: I think it is not duplicated, because multiple li tags made it so complex.

Comment: I think it is. Two answer here propose the same solution as the accepted answer in the other question. The answer is independent from the any structure: Clone the node, remove all element child nodes and   retrieve the remaining text. How to *get* the element you want the text from is a different problem which you already seemed to have solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is clone the element, remove all it's children and use `$.text()` to get the remaining text:

```
$("#one").live("click", function(){
    var partxt = $(this).parent().parent().clone().children().remove().end().text();
    alert(partxt);
});
```

This takes the parent of the parent and clones it. This is so that when we do `.children().remove()` it doesn't affect the displayed elements. `.end()` will "re-select" the parent of the parent of `$(this)` and `.text()` gets the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
$("#one").live("click",function(){
     //It will filter parent li's content to get only text node and get its text
     var partxt = $(this).parent().parent().contents().filter(function(){
                       //return true only if text node
                       return this.nodeType == 3;
                  }).text();
     alert(partxt);
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/TpdfA/

**Side Note:**

If you are using jQuyer ver 1.7+ then it is adviceable to use `on` else you can use delegate instead of using `live`.

Using `delegate()`

```
//Instead of document you can specify any parent container of dynamic elements
$(document).delegate("#one", "click",function(){
     //It will filter parent li's content to get only text node and get its text
     var partxt = $(this).parent().parent().contents().filter(function(){
                       //return true only if text node
                       return this.nodeType == 3;
                  }).text();
     alert(partxt);
});
```

Using `on()` (jQuery ver 1.7+)

```
//Instead of document you can specify any parent container of dynamic elements
$(document).on("click", "#one",function(){
     //It will filter parent li's content to get only text node and get its text
     var partxt = $(this).parent().parent().contents().filter(function(){
                       //return true only if text node
                       return this.nodeType == 3;
                  }).text();
     alert(partxt);
});
```

References:

- `delegate()` - http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
- `on()` - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

This turned into an interesting chain

Dem0: http://jsfiddle.net/fut7y/

```
$('#one').click(function() {
    var topLevelText = $(this).parent().parent().clone().children().remove().end().text();

    alert(topLevelText);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the HTML, turn it into a string, and split on first HTML start tag and then select first value of array to get the first text string.

```
$(document).on("click", "#one", function(){
   var partxt = new String($(this).parent().parent().html()).split('<')[0];
   alert(partxt);
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9WAh3/1/)